# Duplicate checkstyle warnings in a jenkins maven multimodule job

Tags: maven, jenkins, checkstyle

I have a jenkins maven job with an aggregator pom and a bunch of submodules. When jenkins displays the checkstyle warnings it does it like so:

- submodule 1: 10 warnings
- submodule 2: 10 warnings
- Aggregator module: 20 warnings
- Total: 40 warnins

In other words, the aggregator (rightfully?) aggregates the warnings found in the submodules, which wouldn't be such a big problem if it weren't because the *total* then becomes double what it should be.

Does any one know what the problem is? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends on whether you are using the Freestyle project type or the [Evil Maven Project type](http://jenkins.361315.n4.nabble.com/plugins-disabled-when-using-m2-build-td367093.html).

If you are using freestyle, you just need to set your pattern for `checkstyle.xml` results to exclude the aggregator or exclude the sub-projects.

If you are using the evil sibling, you may need to tweak the 'per-module' config to disable the reports for the child modules.

The issue here is that the aggregator module is copying the warnings from the child projects in order to produce an aggregated report.

You could also disable the aggregation when the job runs on Jenkins.

It's basically a fight between the auto-sniffing "magic" from the evil project type and the way the maven-checkstyle-plugin implements the aggregate reporting.

Comment: Thanks! I'm using the "evil type". You must have spent many a day debugging it to hate it so much! ;) Thanks for your answer,I need to work it out. Per-module configuration has no option to disable checkstyle, so I'll have to evaluate what's best/easier...

Comment: Freestyle Project type is the answer. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can adapt some of the tricks from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13430161/preventing-checkstyle-from-running-in-a-specific-maven-submodule/13434712#comment18366114_13434712)

Add the following to the aggregator pom:

```
<project>
  ...
  <profiles>
    ...
    <profile>
      <id>on-jenkins</id>
      <build>
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
            <inherited>false</inherited>
            <configuration>
              <skip>true</skip>
            </configuration>
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
      </build>
    </profile>
    ...
  </profiles>
  ...
</project>
```

And add `-P+on-jenkins` to your Maven goals on the Jenkins job.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That didn't help though :/ jenkins still diligently checks through the submodules, even if checkstyle is not run on the aggregator pom itself. I'm starting to understand your love for the freestyle project :)

Comment: The multimodule one messes with the build behind your back. 90% if the time it works and does what you'd want. But when you hit the 10% it is impossible to correct or prevent its craziness... And then people blame Maven ;hey we're an easy target) when it's actually that project type. One of these days I will write a proper maven integration for Jenkins... KK wants me to, if only to stop me moaning about his m2 project type ;-)

Comment: Also the point is that you'd let Jenkins do the "aggregation" the other option is to switch to the violations plugin for checkstyle. (note: Peter Reilly the author of violations is a friend of mine so I may be biased towards it) in general I find the violations plugin a better option